# Node modules in theme

Tags: javascript, theme, npm

I am new to magento and i have researched this issue i am having for enough time to post it here.

My goal is to understand how require-js works with node modules.

Case:

```
$themeDir = app/design/frontend/<whatever>/<theme_name>

I have `$themeDir/node_modules` installed via npm
I have `$themeDir/require-config.js`
```

1. I want to include in all pages node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/aaa.js
2. I also want to define `node_modules/generic/four/path/bbb.js i`n `$themeDir/Whatever_Module/require-config.js` so i can call it within .phtml templates found in Whatever_Module

How would i go about doing such a thing ?
I don't have any specifics but this is a info case that i need to properly understand.

Comment: It is wonderful how a 2.5k + stack points or whatever with 60+ badges corrects my freaking grammar instead of actually providing an answer. great community

After a 2 hour wait this thread will die in the depths of the internet, but at least Teja bhagavan Kollepara gave me a grammar lesson. FFS